# Detecting overlapping ranges in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have array of ranges :

```
[[39600..82800], [39600..70200],[70200..80480]]
```

I need to determine if there is overlapping or not.What is an easy way to do it in ruby?

In the above case the output should be 'Overlapping'.

Comment: In ActiveSupport there is Range#overlaps? : http://devdocs.io/rails/range#method-i-overlaps-3F

Comment: Technically speaking, you have array of arrays of ranges

Comment: This is great puzzle, however this is not a puzzle site - please post your attempt of solving it, do not ask for ready solutions.

Comment: Do `1..3` and `3..5` "overlap"?

Comment: Hello, @BroiSatse. You've been AWOL.

Comment: @BroiSatse can you take a look at my solution. I feel it solves the puzzle?

Answer (score 9):

This is a very interesting puzzle, especially if you care about performances.

If the ranges are just two, it's a fairly simple algorithm, which is also covered in [`ActiveSupport` `overlaps?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Range.html#method-i-overlaps-3F) extension.

```
def ranges_overlap?(r1, r2)
  r1.cover?(r2.first) || r2.cover?(r1.first)
end
```

If you want to compare multiple ranges, it's a fairly interesting algorithm exercise.

You could loop over all the ranges, but you will need to compare each range with all the other possibilities, but this is an algorithm with exponential cost.

A more efficient solution is to [order the ranges](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=841368) and execute a binary search, or to use data structures (such as trees) to make possible to compute the overlapping.

This problem is also explained in the [Interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Intersecting) page. Computing an overlap essentially consists of finding the intersection of the trees.

Comment: It would be quadratic cost I think, O(n^2), rather than exponential cost, O(c^n). If n is guaranteed to be small, then it would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Is this not a way to do it?

```
def any_overlapping_ranges(array_of_ranges)
   array_of_ranges.sort_by(&:first).each_cons(2).any?{|x,y|x.last>y.first}
end

p any_overlapping_ranges([50..100, 1..51,200..220]) #=> True
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider this:

```
class Range
  include Comparable

  def <=>(other)
    self.begin <=> other.begin
  end

  def self.overlap?(*ranges)
    edges = ranges.sort.flat_map { |range| [range.begin, range.end] }
    edges != edges.sort.uniq
  end
end

Range.overlap?(2..12, 6..36, 42..96) # => true
```

**Notes**:

1. This could take in any number of ranges.
2. Have a look at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/JikkuJose/9f136adbf994ef9884e7) with some tests to play with the code.
3. The code creates a *flat* array with the start and end of each range.
4. This array will retain the order if they don't overlap. (Its easier to visualize with some examples than textually explaining why, try it).

Comment: Rails has `Range#overlap?`, so be careful when monkey patching the `Range` class when using Rails =)

Answer (score 1):

For sake of simplicity and readability I'll suggest this approach:

```
def overlaps?(ranges)
  ranges.each_with_index do |range, index|
    (index..ranges.size).each do |i|
      nextRange = ranges[i] unless index == i
      if nextRange and  range.to_a & nextRange.to_a 
        puts "#{range} overlaps with #{nextRange}"
      end
    end
  end
end


r = [(39600..82800), (39600..70200),(70200..80480)]
overlaps?(r)
```

and the output:

```
ruby ranges.rb 
39600..82800 overlaps with 39600..70200
39600..82800 overlaps with 70200..80480
39600..70200 overlaps with 70200..80480
```