# How to validate overlapping times in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `Event model` that has `form` time and `to` time in my schedule app and I want to validate the overlapping time before saving.

My view image as followings;

```
Departure date: Dec 31, 2016

Day1
07:00 - 07:20 event1
10:30 - 11:30 event2
15:40 - 16:10 event3
[add event button]

Day2
08:15 - 09:05 event4
12:08 - 13:04 event5
14:00 - 14:25 event6
[add event button]

[save schedule button]
```

`from` time and `to` time can be changed and added at the same time.

What I'd like to do is to display error if I try to add (or change to) `07:05 - 07:30` for `Day1`, for example, `13:50 - 14:30` for `Day2` and so on.

Although I tried some codes with `overlap`, `between`, `cover` with referring to  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030931/detecting-overlapping-ranges-in-ruby) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682638/finding-records-that-overlap-a-range-in-rails) and so on, I haven't be able to apply them to my code.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time     "from"
    t.time     "to"
    t.integer  "room_id"
    ...

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "schedule_id"
    ...

  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "departure_date"
    ...
```

Give the following **models**:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rooms, inverse_of: :schedule
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
  ...

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :rooms
  has_many :events, inverse_of: :room
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
  ...

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :events
  has_one :schedule, autosave: false, through: :room
  ...
```

**_schedule_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  <br>
    <%= f.label :departure_date %>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
      <%= f.text_field :departure_date, :value => (f.object.departure_date.strftime('%b/%d/%Y') if f.object.departure_date), class: 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format:'MMM-DD-YYYY'});
    });
  </script>
  <br>
  <div id="room">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |a| %>
      <div id="room_<%= a.object.object_id %>">
        <p class="day-number-element-selector"><b>Day&nbsp;<%= a.index.to_i + 1 %></b></p>

        <%= a.simple_fields_for :events do |e| %>
          <span class="form-inline">
            <p>
              <%= e.input :from, label: false %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <%= e.input :to, label: false %>
            </p>
          </span>
          <%= e.input :title, label: false %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <%= a.link_to_add "Add event", :events, data: {target: "#room_#{a.object.object_id}"}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

      <%= a.input :room %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to check and display error.

**EDIT!**

still not work

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :assign_date
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :events
  has_one :schedule, autosave: false, through: :room
  validate :cannot_overlap_another_event

scope :in_range, -> range {
  where('(\'from\' BETWEEN ? AND ?)', range.first, range.last)
}
scope :exclude_self, -> id { where.not(id: id) }

def cannot_overlap_another_event
  range = Range.new from, to
  overlaps = Event.exclude_self(id).in_range(range)
  overlap_error unless overlaps.empty?
end

def overlap_error
  errors.add(:overlap_error, 'There is already an event scheduled in this hour!')
end
```

**development.log**

```
....
Started POST "/schedules" for 218.33.213.91 at 2016-04-07 11:44:59 +0000
Processing by SchedulesController#create as HTML
...
      [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  begin transaction
      [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND (('from' BETWEEN '2016-04-07 07:00:00.000000' AND '2016-04-07 07:20:00.000000'))[0m
      [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND (('from' BETWEEN '2016-04-07 07:05:00.000000' AND '2016-04-07 07:30:00.000000'))
      [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schedules" ("title", "departure_date", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["title", "test title"], ["departure_date", "2016-04-10"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-04-07 11:45:00.061460"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-07 11:45:00.061460"]]
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you need a server side validation, you could implement some `custom` validators in your model class:

```
validate :cannot_overlap_another_event
```

Next you need to code this method yourself:

```
def cannot_overlap_another_event
  range = Range.new from, to
  overlaps = Appointment.exclude_self(id).in_range(range)
  overlap_error unless overlaps.empty?
end
```

Explaining what this code do, you create a `Range` object with your `from` and `to` dates. Then it uses the helper scopes to exclude the `Event` itself and check to see if there's an event in this range.

```
scope :in_range, -> range {
  where('(from BETWEEN ? AND ?)', range.first, range.last)
}
scope :exclude_self, -> id { where.not(id: id) }
```

The `overlap_error` is a method that populates the model's error hash to display on screen:

```
def overlap_error
  errors.add(:overlap_error, 'There is already an event scheduled in this hour!')
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MurifoX. Although I edited `event.rb`, `NoMethodError (undefined method "from" for 2016-04-06 12:39:00 UTC..2016-04-06 12:40:00 UTC:Range):`, `app/models/event.rb:17:in "block in <class:Event>"`, `app/models/event.rb:23:in "cannot_overlap_another_event"`, `app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:37:in "create"` were displayed when I try to create new schedule. I updated `event.rb` at the bottom of  my question.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue Ops, my bad, you should use `range.first` and `range.last`, not your model attribute names.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, @MurifoX. Another error `SQLite3::SQLException (no such column: start):` was displayed. Sorry for asking again before I search the meaning of this error.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue It is because the query is using `where('(start`, in your case the `start` date is named `from`. It was because of my copy and paste here, haha. Just change it to `from` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your update, @MurifoX. Next error is `SQLite3::SQLException (near "from": syntax error):`. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue maybe your dates are in the wrong format (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates). Also it is a good practice to use other database like `postgres` in development. This way you don't have surprises when testing things in production when you use another database that is not SQLite3

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @MurifoX. I found out this error appeared because `from` is SQL keyword.  No error is displayed after using `\'from\'` instead of `from` for now. I'll try to rename this column and use postgres later. Although no error is displayed, the validation doesn't work. It would be appreciated if you could give me a hint.

Comment: I added `development.log` at the bottom of my question, @MurifoX. Are these SQL correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108514/discussion-between-murifox-and-samuraiblue).

Comment: Although my question wasn't solved, I will try postgres.

Comment: Although I managed to configure postgresql, the result is the same. I created [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575174/how-to-validate-overlapping-times-in-rails-with-postgresql). It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion, @MurifoX.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this https://makandracards.com/makandra/984-test-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-ruby-or-rails. The key is to define one scope to chek for overlapping siblings. Somthing like this:

```
# Return a scope for all interval overlapping the given interval, including the given interval itself
  named_scope :overlapping, lambda { |interval| {
    :conditions => ["id <> ? AND (DATEDIFF(start_date, ?) * DATEDIFF(?, end_date)) >= 0", interval.id, interval.end_date, interval.start_date]
  }}
```

Also you can check this gem: https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap I think it can help.

Comment: That validates_overlap gem was a lifesaver! That should be the real accepted answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `EventsController#Create` & `EventsController#Update` methods check for new time in between the old times like :

```
events = Event.where(:departure_date => event_params[:departure_date])
events.each do |event|
 if event_params[:to].between?(event.to, event.from) || event_params[:from].between?(event.to, event.from)
  flash[:error] = "Current Slot Time is already taken!"
  redirect_to :back
  return
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a project, my solution is to include a validation method inside the model, so I have a model for vacation periods taken and I must add periods (lapses) taking care that those lapses are not overlapping; Suppose you have a collection of lapses taken (active_permits) and you just got a new lapse from your form (lapse) then there are only two fundamental rules that will determine if the two periods are overlapping: lapse[:end] must be smaller (that is occurs earlier) than active_permit[:start] OR lapse[:start] must be greater (occurs later) than active_permit[:end], so UNLESS one of these rules are met, the two periods overlap. Code must be something like this:

```
def lapse_validation(lapse)
  error = 0
  @active_permits.each do |active_permit|
    unless (lapse[:end] < active_permit[:start] || lapse[:start] > active_permit[:end])
      error = 1
      errors.add(:new_permit, ": The dates you entered overlapp an existing leave period")
    end
  end
  return error
end
```

You can find a more detailed discussion on overlapping periods here: https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/determining-two-date-ranges-overlap/