# How to validate overlapping times in Rails with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `Event model` that has `start_at` time and `end_at` time in my schedule app and I want to validate the overlapping time before saving.

I create my rails app on **Cloud9**.

My view image as followings;

```
Day1
07:00 - 07:20 event1
10:30 - 11:30 event2
15:40 - 16:10 event3
[add event button]

Day2
08:15 - 09:05 event4
12:08 - 13:04 event5
14:00 - 14:25 event6
[add event button]

[save schedule button]
```

`start_at` time and `end_at` time can be changed and added at the same time.

What I'd like to do is to display error if I try to add (or change to) `07:05 - 07:30` for `Day1`, for example, `13:50 - 14:30` for `Day2` and so on.

For example;

**app_development=# select * from events;**

```
 id | start_at |  end_at  | title  | detail | schedule_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+----------+----------+--------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 07:00:00 | 07:20:00 | event1 |        |               1 | 2016-04-12 05:28:44.166827 | 2016-04-12 12:52:07.682872
  2 | 10:30:00 | 11:30:00 | event2 |        |               1 | 2016-04-12 05:28:44.17747  | 2016-04-12 12:52:07.689934
  3 | 15:40:00 | 16:10:00 | event3 |        |               1 | 2016-04-12 05:29:07.5005   | 2016-04-12 12:52:07.693477
```

I added `07:05 - 07:30` above table, but the validation doesn't work.

Although I asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449818/how-to-validate-overlapping-times-in-rails), I was advised to use postgresql instead of sqlite3.

So I managed to configure postgresql, but the result is the same.
It would be appreciated if you could give me how to check and display error.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time     "start_at"
    t.time     "end_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "room_id"
    ...

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "room"
    t.integer  "schedule_id"
    ...

  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "departure_date"
    ...
```

Give the following **models**:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :events
  has_one :schedule, autosave: false, through: :room
  ...
  validate :cannot_overlap_another_event

  def cannot_overlap_another_event
    range = Range.new start_at, end_at
    overlaps = Event.exclude_self(id).in_range(range)
    overlap_error unless overlaps.empty?
  end

  scope :in_range, -> range {
    where('(start_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)', range.first, range.last)
  }
  scope :exclude_self, -> id { where.not(id: id) }

  def overlap_error
    errors.add(:overlap_error, 'There is already an event scheduled in this hour!')
  end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rooms, inverse_of: :schedule
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
  ...

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :rooms
  has_many :events, inverse_of: :room
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
  ...
```

**_schedule_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  <br>
    <%= f.label :departure_date %>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
      <%= f.text_field :departure_date, :value => (f.object.departure_date if f.object.departure_date), class: 'form-control' %>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format:'YYYY-MM-DD'});
    });
  </script>
  <br>
  <div id="room">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |a| %>
  <div id="room_<%= a.object.object_id %>">
        <p class="day-number-element-selector"><b>Day&nbsp;<%= a.index.to_i + 1 %></b></p>

        <%= a.simple_fields_for :events do |e| %>
          <span class="form-inline">
            <p>
              <%= e.input :start_at, label: false %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <%= e.input :end_at, label: false %>
            </p>
          </span>
          <%= e.input :title, label: false %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <%= a.link_to_add "Add event", :events, data: {target: "#room_#{a.object.object_id}"}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

      <%= a.input :room %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to check and display error.

**EDIT**

edit as followings;

**event.rb**

```
scope :in_range, -> range {
  where('(start_at BETWEEN ? AND ? OR end_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (start_at <= ? AND end_at >= ?)', range.first, range.last, range.first, range.last, range.first, range.last)
}
```

Although it seems to work, this validate doesn't work when I add `event` on a different day as following `id=8`. (see `created_at` and `updated_at`)

**app_development=# select * from events;**

```
id | start_at |  end_at  | title  | detail | room_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+----------+----------+--------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 07:00:00 | 07:20:00 | event1 |        |               1 | 2016-04-12 05:28:44.166827 | 2016-04-12 12:52:07.682872
  2 | 10:30:00 | 11:30:00 | event2 |        |               1 | 2016-04-12 05:28:44.17747  | 2016-04-12 12:52:07.689934
  3 | 15:40:00 | 16:10:00 | event3 |        |               1 | 2016-04-12 05:29:07.5005   | 2016-04-12 12:52:07.693477
  8 | 07:05:00 | 07:10:00 | event4 |        |               1 | 2016-04-15 21:37:58.569868 | 2016-04-15 21:39:27.956737
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope is headed in the right direct, but doesn't cover all your cases.

```
scope :in_range, -> range {
  where('(start_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)', range.first, range.last)
}
```

In your example, you end up checking `start_at BETWEEN 7:05 AND 7:30`, but `start_at` on Day 1 is `7:00`, which is outside that range.

There are four cases you need to handle:

```
New range overlaps start
Existing:     |------------|
New:      |-------|

New range overlaps end
Existing: |------------|
New:               |-------|

New range inside existing range
Existing: |------------|
New:         |-------|

Existing range inside new range
Existing:    |-------|
New:      |------------|
```

Looking, you can see that the first three cases are handled by checking if

```sql
new_start BETWEEN start_at AND end_at
OR
new_end   BETWEEN start_at AND end_at
```

Then you just need to catch the fourth case by adding

```sql
OR
start_at BETWEEN new_start AND new_end
```

You could add a similar check on `end_at` for code symmetry, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Kristján. I tried to edit the validation such as at the bottom of my question. But this validation doesn't work when I try to add `event` on a different day. I edited the source at the bottom of my question. It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any representation of which day an event is on in your DB. You need to add that, and then you can also consider `AND new_day = existing_day`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment, @Kristján. Is it impossible to check only `start_at` and `end_at` ? Because only times (not date) seems to be stored in these fields when I tried to `select` sql as I added at the bottom of my question.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. How do you expect to compare whether things are on the same day when you don't store that? If you want to store an actual date, you should make your columns `timestamp`s. If your days are a sequence (1, 2, 3, ...) not actually tied to one date, you need a column for it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Kristján. You answerd my first question, I accepted your answer. I will consider later `AND new_day = existing_day` you advised.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel in PostgreSQL, there are two implemented simple methods to achieve overlap checks:

1. SQL's [`OVERLAPS` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

Simple enough,

```
where("(start_at, end_at) OVERLAPS (?, ?)", range.first, range.last)
```

However this enables one range to be exactly after the other
(in other words, it checks *start <= time < end*).

2. [Range types'](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) [`&&` (overlaps) operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html):

This is simple too, usually. But PostgreSQL doesn't have a built-in range type for `time` (however there are `tsrange`, `tstzrange`, and `daterange` for the other temporal types).

You need to create this range type for yourself:

```
CREATE TYPE timerange AS RANGE (subtype = time);
```

But after this, you can check overlapping with

```
where("timerange(start_at, end_at) && timerange(?, ?)", range.first, range.last)
```

Pros of range types:

- you can control yourself, how do you want to handle range boundaries

  f.ex. you could use `timerange(start_at, end_at, '[]')` to include both the start & the end-point of the ranges. By default it includes the start, but excludes the end-point of the ranges.
- it can be indexed, f.ex. with

  ```
  CREATE INDEX events_times_idx ON events USING GIST (timerange(start_at, end_at));
  ```
- [Exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION): this is essentially the same, what you want to achieve, but it will be enforced at DB level (like, `UNIQUE` or any other constraints):

  ```
  ALTER TABLE events
    ADD CONSTRAINT events_exclude_overlapping
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (timerange(start_at, end_at) WITH &&);
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @pozs. Although I voted `this answer is useful`, I tried to apply another answer. Because this is first time to use postgresql. I will try to understand your advice later. By the way, it would appreciated if you could give me any suggestion at the bottom of my question

Comment: @SamuraiBlue that's because you didn't apply the one you accepted. That would be `where("? BETWEEN start_at AND end_at OR ? BETWEEN start_at AND end_at OR start_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", range.first, range.last, range.first, range.last)`