# How to validate input against Database records to avoid overlapping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on appointment management app with Ruby on Rails, and trying to implement overlapping validation. Appointments have start and end times (not in DateTime format, just plain integers)

Tried to use Ranges, but it did not work

Expecting to achieve the following:

Database existing records:

`[{id:1, start_time:0; end_time:10}, {id:2, start_time:20, end_time:40}]`

Should validate a new appointment object to make sure it does not overlap with other appointments, i.e.

`{id:15, start_time:11, end_time:19}` should be saved successfully

`{id:16, start_time:1, end_time:9}` should not be saved (overlaps with another appointment(id 1))

Comment: A database validation is good to have and a nice last resort but I'd try to catch this sooner if you can for the UX. Try to validate this on the front-end with JS.

Comment: This is a backend only project, so I have no way of validating it on FE (i'd love to do that though)

Comment: We have this issue as well in one of our systems (we call them time_frames) and you will need to validate 3 things 1) that the new one does not intersect an existing time frame 2) that it is not encompassed by another time frame 3) that it does not encompass another time frame. They are all fairly simple 1 and 2 are just check that start does not fall between another start and end and that end does not fall between another start and end. 3 is the same except you need to ensure no existing start or end falls inside your new one

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom validation. Instead of `validates`, you'd use `validate`. You're going to want to use dates, though. With pure integers you'll only be able to handle one day unless you're deleting all the records each day (which you're not going to want to do). Pseudo-code inside the def.

```
validate :no_overlap, on: :save

def no_overlap
  # iterate through appointments on that date
  # check for the overlap
  # if overlap exists
  # self.errors.add("Overlaps with existing appointment!")
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449818/how-to-validate-overlapping-times-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

First off change those columns to datetime or time types so that you can actually use the databases date functions. Why use integers when your database can actually represent times/dates properly?

SQL has an `OVERLAPS` keyword that can be used to check for overlaps between two timestamps:

```
SELECT  "appointments".* FROM "appointments" 
WHERE ((start_time, end_time) OVERLAPS (a, b))
```

Postgres supports it. MySQL being a peasant database requires [a hacky workaround](https://makandracards.com/makandra/984-test-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-ruby-or-rails).

You can create a "scope" from this by:

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  def self.overlapping(range)
    self.where('(?,?) OVERLAPS (starts_at, ends_at)', range.begin, range.end)
  end
end
```

You can then use the scope in a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators):

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :time_available
  def self.overlapping(range)
    self.where('(?,?) OVERLAPS (starts_at, ends_at)', range.begin, range.end)
  end

  def time_available
    if self.class.overlapping(start_time..end_time).exists?
      errors.add(:base, "time is not available") 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is just basically a nudge in the right direction. In the end you will probably need much more complex logic in the validation to check which of its the start or end that overlaps so that you can give better feedback.