# How to merge overlapping structures with ranges in them

Tags: ruby

I have a class `Format`, which is a data structure carrying information about text formatting:

```
Format = Struct.new(:from, :to, :attributes)
```

(I don't care whether it is `Format.new(from, to, attrs)` or `Format.new(range, attrs)`.)

Among `Format` instances `f1` and `f2`, I want to define an operation `merge_formats(f1, f2)`, which merges overlapping formats, for example when syntax highlighting and selection should be applied to the same region of text. Similarly for cases where the ranges are disjunct, overlap only on one side, etc. It is described by the following diagrams:

```
INPUT:
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
format1 = | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | , attributes1
          +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      +---+---+---+---+
format2 =             | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | , attributes2
                      +---+---+---+---+

RESULT:
          +---+---+---+
part1 =   | 1 | 2 | 3 |, attributes1 
          +---+---+---+
                      +---+---+---+---+
part2 =               | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | , attributes1 + attributes2
                      +---+---+---+---+
                                      +---+---+
part3 =                               | 8 | 9 | , attributes1
                                      +---+---+
```

Particular application should look like this:

```
merge_formats(Format.new(1, 9, attributes1), Format.new(4, 7, attributes2))
# => [Format.new(1, 3, attributes1), Format.new(4, 7, attributes1 + attributes2), Format.new(8, 9, attributes1)]
```

`attribute1` and `attribute2` are anything that can be added, in this case flags (integers, hence the `|` operator). If they were `:attribute1` and `:attribute2`, then as the addition" operation would be `Array.push`, and the result could be:

```
# => [Format.new(1, 3, [:attribute1]), Format.new(4, 7, [:attribute1, :attribute2]), Format.new(8, 9, [:attribute1])]
```

Is there a nice Ruby way how to solve this?

---

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030931), in which one of the answers cleverly uses `flat_map` to detect the edges, but that's not usable in my case, as the other information is lost. I came up with this, and I don't like it:

```
Format = Struct.new(:from, :to, :attributes) do
  def self.compare(f1, f2)
    if f2.from < f1.from && f2.to > f1.to
      :includes
    elsif f2.from >= f1.from && f2.to <= f1.to
      :inside
    elsif f2.from < f1.from && (f1.from..f1.to).include?(f2.to)
      :left
    elsif (f1.from..f1.to).include?(f2.from) && f2.to > f1.to
      :right
    else
      :outside
    end
  end

  def self.merge(f1, f2)
    case compare(f1, f2)
    when :includes
      [Format.new(f2.from, f1.from-1, f2.attributes),
       Format.new(f2.from, f1.to, f1.attributes | f2.attributes),
       Format.new(f1.to+1, f2.to, f2.attributes),
      ]
    when :inside
      if f2.from == f1.from && f2.to == f1.to
        [Format.new(f2.from, f2.to, f1.attributes | f2.attributes)]
      else
        [Format.new(f1.from, f2.from-1, f1.attributes),
         Format.new(f2.from, f2.to, f1.attributes | f2.attributes),
         Format.new(f2.to+1, f1.to, f1.attributes),
        ]
      end
    when :left
      r = [Format.new(f2.from, f1.from-1, f2.attributes),
           Format.new(f1.from, f2.to, f1.attributes | f2.attributes)]
      r << Format.new(f2.to+1, f1.to, f1.attributes) if f2.to != f1.to
      r
    when :right
      r = []
      r << Format.new(f1.from, f2.from-1, f1.attributes) if f2.from != f1.from
      r << Format.new(f2.from, f1.to, f1.attributes | f2.attributes)
      r << Format.new(f1.to+1, f2.to, f2.attributes)
      r
    else
      if f2.from < f1.from
        [f2, f1]
      else
        [f1, f2]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The attributes are constants (e.g, `FOO`) whose values are not given (and `FOO | BAR` only makes sense for certain values of those constants). Do youactually mean `FOO` to be a literal, such as `:FOO` or `"FOO"`? If so, please edit and consider `[Format.new(10, 12, [:FOO]), Format.new(13, 16, [:FOO, :BAR]), Format.new(17, 20, [:FOO])]` as the desired return value. I assume `[:FOO]` in `[Format.new(10, 12, [:FOO])` means the range `10..12` is wholly within the range `10..20` and not wholly within `12..16`. Is that correct?

Comment: I edited the question and added a working code example. I hope that makes things clearer. Thank you!

Comment: Very clear now, except I don't think you answered the last question of my earlier comment (whether it is `[:FOO, :BAR]` or `FOO | BAR`). I could perhaps answer it by studying your code, but an explanation (by way of an edit) would be helpful. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Edited again. I changed FOO and BAR to something more meaningful and added an illustration to clarify the whole thing. If the two ranges were `10..12` and `12..16`, they would overlap on the 12th item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Structure of solution**

I have defined

```
Format = Struct.new(:range, :attributes)
```

and instances of the class `Format` such as

```
Format.new(10..20, :BAR)
```

Here `@attribute` equals a symbol but it could be any Ruby object.

I will then construct and return an array of instances of `Format` such as

```
Format.new(12..15, [:FOO, :BAR])
```

This is interpreted as meaning that the original instances of `Format` for which `@attributes` equal `:FOO` and `:BAR` have values of `@range` that cover the interval `12..15`. Moreover, these instances of `Format` (for which the value of `@attributes` is an array) have the non-overlapping ranges asked for by the question. The order of the elements in the arrays (the values of `@attributes`) is not specified.

The values (arrays) of `@attributes` can then be manipulate as desired. For example, `[3,5]` might be converted to `3|5`.

**Code**

```
def merge_formats(*formats)
  fmod = formats.map { |e| Format.new(e.range, [e.attributes]) }.
                 sort_by { |e| e.range.begin }
  a = []
  while fmod.any?
    b = []
    while fmod.any? && (b.empty? || (fmod.first.range.begin == b.first.range.begin))
      b << fmod.shift
    end
    next_end = b.min_by { |f| f.range.end }.range.end
    next_end = [next_end, fmod.first.range.begin-1].min if fmod.any?
    a << Format.new(b.first.range.begin..next_end, b.map { |f| f.attributes.first })
    while b.any?
      f = b.shift
      fmod.unshift(Format.new(next_end+1..f.range.end, f.attributes)) if
        f.range.end > next_end
    end
  end
  a
end
```

**Examples**

```
Format = Struct.new(:range, :attributes)

f1 = Format.new(10..20, :FOO)
f2 = Format.new(12..16, :BAR)
merge_formats(f1, f2)
  #=> [#<struct Format range=10..11, attributes=[:FOO]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=12..16, attributes=[:FOO, :BAR]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=17..20, attributes=[:FOO]>]

f1 = Format.new(12..16, :BAR)
f2 = Format.new(10..11, :FOO)
merge_formats(f1, f2)
  #=> [#<struct Format range=10..11, attributes=[:FOO]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=12..16, attributes=[:BAR]>]

f1 = Format.new(12..16, :BAR)
f2 = Format.new(10..20, :FOO)
f3 = Format.new(14..24, :BAZ)
f4 = Format.new(15..18, :QUX)
merge_formats(f1, f2, f3, f4)
  #=> [#<struct Format range=10..11, attributes=[:FOO]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=12..13, attributes=[:FOO, :BAR]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=14..14, attributes=[:BAR, :FOO, :BAZ]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=15..16, attributes=[:BAZ, :FOO, :BAR, :QUX]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=17..18, attributes=[:QUX, :FOO, :BAZ]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=19..20, attributes=[:BAZ, :FOO]>,
  #    #<struct Format range=21..24, attributes=[:BAZ]>]
```

Comment: Impressive piece of code, I'm still trying to wrap my brain around it, thank you! I forgot to add that I'm quite new to Ruby, so this answer will probably take me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (I'm not an expert Rubyist) :

```
# file .../split_range/lib/t.rb

class SplitRange
        # Answer a hash.
        # There will be two or three of the following keys :
        # :ar1left  : part of range1 outside and left of range2
        # :br2left  : part of range2 outside and left of range1
        # :ccommon  : part common to range1 and range2
        # :dr1right : part of range1 outside and right of range2
        # :er2right : part of range2 outside and right of range1
        # Note : letters a b c d e have been added to help writing test expectations
        #        in the same order as the result of merge.
        # The value is an array of numbers from ranges.
    def partition(p_range1, p_range2)
#        puts "r1=#{p_range1}  r2=#{p_range2}"
        group1 = p_range1.group_by{ | e | e < p_range2.first ? :ar1left : p_range2.cover?(e) ? :ccommon : :dr1right }
        group2 = p_range2.group_by{ | e | e < p_range1.first ? :br2left : p_range1.cover?(e) ? :ccommon : :er2right }
        group1.merge(group2)
    end
end # class SplitRange

class Format < Struct.new(:from, :to, :attributes)
    def self.merge(f1, f2)
        formats = []
        groups = SplitRange.new.partition(f1.from..f1.to, f2.from..f2.to)
        #puts groups
        groups.sort_by{ | k, v | k}.each do | key, value |
            case key
            when :ar1left
                formats << Format.new(value.first, value.last, f1.attributes)
            when :br2left
                formats << Format.new(value.first, value.last, f2.attributes)
            when :ccommon
                formats << Format.new(value.first, value.last, f1.attributes | f2.attributes)
            when :dr1right
                formats << Format.new(value.first, value.last, f1.attributes)
            when :er2right
                formats << Format.new(value.first, value.last, f2.attributes)
            end
        end

        formats
    end
end # class Format

if __FILE__ == $0
then
    f1 = Format.new(1, 9, [:foo])
    f2 = Format.new(4, 7, [:bar])
    puts Format.merge(f1, f2)
end
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w lib/t.rb 
#<struct Format from=1, to=3, attributes=[:foo]>
#<struct Format from=4, to=7, attributes=[:foo, :bar]>
#<struct Format from=8, to=9, attributes=[:foo]>
```

I have written two RSpec tests, one to test `SplitRange` :

```
# file .../split_range/spec/t_split_spec.rb

require 't'

RSpec.describe SplitRange do
    describe '#partition' do
        let(:rleft)      {  1..5 }
        let(:rcenter)    { 10..20 }
        let(:rright)     { 24..26 }
        let(:rovleft)    { 8..12 }
        let(:rinside)    { 12..16 }
        let(:rovright)   { 18..24 }
        let(:rleft_a)    { rleft.to_a }
        let(:rcenter_a)  { rcenter.to_a }
        let(:rright_a)   { rright.to_a }
        let(:rovleft_a)  { rovleft.to_a }
        let(:rinside_a)  { rinside.to_a }
        let(:rovright_a) { rovright.to_a }

        def helperCommon(a1, a2)
            # answers elements common to both arrays
            a1.select { | e | a2.include?(e) } 
        end

        context 'non overlapping' do
            it 'values of r1 smaller than r2 go to :ar1left' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rleft, rcenter)
                expect(groups[:ar1left]).to eq(rleft_a)
            end

            it 'values of r2 smaller than r1 go to :br2left' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rcenter, rleft)
                expect(groups[:br2left]).to eq(rleft_a)
            end

            it 'values of r1 greater than r2 go to :dr1right' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rright, rcenter)
                expect(groups[:dr1right]).to eq(rright_a)
            end

            it 'values of r2 greater than r1 go to :er2right' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rcenter, rright)
                expect(groups[:er2right]).to eq(rright_a)
            end
        end # context 'non overlapping'

        context 'overlapping r2 from left to right' do
            it 'values of r2 smaller than r1 go to :br2left' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rcenter, rovleft)
                expect(groups[:br2left]).to eq(rovleft_a - rcenter_a)
            end

            it 'values of r2 (left) common to r1 go to :ccommon' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rcenter, rovleft)
                expect(groups[:ccommon]).to eq(helperCommon(rcenter_a, rovleft_a))
            end

            it 'values of r2 (inside) common to r1 go to :ccommon' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rcenter, rinside)
                expect(groups[:ccommon]).to eq(helperCommon(rcenter_a, rinside_a))
            end

            it 'values of r2 (right) common to r1 go to :ccommon' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rcenter, rovright)
                expect(groups[:ccommon]).to eq(helperCommon(rcenter_a, rovright_a))
            end

            it 'values of r2 greater than r1 go to :er2right' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rcenter, rovright)
                expect(groups[:er2right]).to eq(rovright_a - rcenter_a)
            end
        end # context 'overlapping r2 from left to right'

        context 'overlapping r1 from left to right' do
            it 'values of r1 smaller than r2 go to :ar1left' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rovleft, rcenter)
                expect(groups[:ar1left]).to eq(rovleft_a - rcenter_a)
            end

            it 'values of r1 (left) common to r2 go to :ccommon' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rovleft, rcenter)
                expect(groups[:ccommon]).to eq(helperCommon(rovleft_a, rcenter_a))
            end

            it 'values of r1 (inside) common to r2 go to :ccommon' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rinside, rcenter)
                expect(groups[:ccommon]).to eq(helperCommon(rinside_a, rcenter_a))
            end

            it 'values of r1 (right) common to r2 go to :ccommon' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rovright, rcenter)
                expect(groups[:ccommon]).to eq(helperCommon(rovright_a, rcenter_a))
            end

            it 'values of r1 greater than r2 go to :dr1right' do
                groups = SplitRange.new.partition(rovright, rcenter)
                expect(groups[:dr1right]).to eq(rovright_a - rcenter_a)
            end
        end # context 'overlapping r1 from left to right'
    end # describe '#partition'
end # describe SplitRange
```

and one to test `merge` :

```
# file .../split_range/spec/t_merge_spec.rb

require 't'

RSpec.describe Format do
    describe '.merge' do
=begin
        let(:rleft)      {  1..5 }
        let(:rcenter)    { 10..20 }
        let(:rright)     { 24..26 }
        let(:rovleft)    { 8..12 }
        let(:rinside)    { 12..16 }
        let(:rovright)   { 18..24 }
=end
        context 'moving r1 over r2' do
            it 'non overlapping r1 on the left of r2' do
                f1 = Format.new(1, 5, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(10, 20, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to eq([Format.new(1, 5, [:foo]), Format.new(10, 20, [:bar])])
            end

            it 'overlapping r1 on the left of r2' do
                f1 = Format.new(8, 12, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(10, 20, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to \
                    eq([Format.new(8, 9, [:foo]), Format.new(10, 12, [:foo, :bar]), Format.new(13, 20, [:bar])])
            end

            it 'overlapping r1 inside r2' do
                f1 = Format.new(12, 16, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(10, 20, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to \
                    eq([Format.new(10, 11, [:bar]), Format.new(12, 16, [:foo, :bar]), Format.new(17, 20, [:bar])])
            end

            it 'overlapping r1 on the right of r2' do
                f1 = Format.new(18, 24, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(10, 20, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to \
                    eq([Format.new(10, 17, [:bar]), Format.new(18, 20, [:foo, :bar]), Format.new(21, 24, [:foo])])
            end

            it 'non overlapping r1 on the right of r2' do
                f1 = Format.new(24, 26, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(10, 20, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to eq([Format.new(10, 20, [:bar]), Format.new(24, 26, [:foo])])
            end
        end # context 'moving r1 over r2'

        context 'moving r2 under r1' do
            it 'non overlapping r2 on the left of r1' do
                f1 = Format.new(10, 20, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(1, 5, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to eq([Format.new(1, 5, [:bar]), Format.new(10, 20, [:foo])])
            end

            it 'overlapping r2 on the left of r1' do
                f1 = Format.new(10, 20, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(8, 12, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to \
                    eq([Format.new(8, 9, [:bar]), Format.new(10, 12, [:foo, :bar]), Format.new(13, 20, [:foo])])
            end

            it 'overlapping r2 inside r1' do
                f1 = Format.new(10, 20, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(12, 16, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to \
                    eq([Format.new(10, 11, [:foo]), Format.new(12, 16, [:foo, :bar]), Format.new(17, 20, [:foo])])
            end

            it 'overlapping r2 on the right of r1' do
                f1 = Format.new(10, 20, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(18, 24, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to \
                    eq([Format.new(10, 17, [:foo]), Format.new(18, 20, [:foo, :bar]), Format.new(21, 24, [:bar])])
            end

            it 'non overlapping r2 on the right of r1' do
                f1 = Format.new(10, 20, [:foo])
                f2 = Format.new(24, 26, [:bar])
                expect(Format.merge(f1, f2)).to eq([Format.new(10, 20, [:foo]), Format.new(24, 26, [:bar])])
            end
        end # context 'moving r1 over r2'
    end # describe '.merge'
end # describe Format
```

Execution :

```
$ rspec -fd

Format
  .merge
    moving r1 over r2
      non overlapping r1 on the left of r2
      overlapping r1 on the left of r2
      overlapping r1 inside r2
      overlapping r1 on the right of r2
      non overlapping r1 on the right of r2
    moving r2 under r1
      non overlapping r2 on the left of r1
      overlapping r2 on the left of r1
      overlapping r2 inside r1
      overlapping r2 on the right of r1
      non overlapping r2 on the right of r1

SplitRange
  #partition
    non overlapping
      values of r1 smaller than r2 go to :ar1left
      values of r2 smaller than r1 go to :br2left
      values of r1 greater than r2 go to :dr1right
      values of r2 greater than r1 go to :er2right
    overlapping r2 from left to right
      values of r2 smaller than r1 go to :br2left
      values of r2 (left) common to r1 go to :ccommon
      values of r2 (inside) common to r1 go to :ccommon
      values of r2 (right) common to r1 go to :ccommon
      values of r2 greater than r1 go to :er2right
    overlapping r1 from left to right
      values of r1 smaller than r2 go to :ar1left
      values of r1 (left) common to r2 go to :ccommon
      values of r1 (inside) common to r2 go to :ccommon
      values of r1 (right) common to r2 go to :ccommon
      values of r1 greater than r2 go to :dr1right

Finished in 0.0093 seconds (files took 0.11066 seconds to load)
24 examples, 0 failures
```

All tests are green (Ruby 2.4, RSpec 3.6).